# Facebook invite Canvas page does not load

Tags: facebook, invite

I've implemented Facebook Invite as follows: - http://www.jobwalk.com.au/invite.aspx

You can login via Facebook and go through the steps (no database update) from: - http://www.jobwalk.com.au

The problem is, when I select someone and press Send Invite and in the final stages, it does not load the Callback or Canvas URL. It just has a Facebook page with a Blank Page in its IFRAME.

**Facebook application values**

- Site URL: http://www.jobwalk.com.au/
- Canvas URL: http://www.jobwalk.com.au/callback/
- Canvas FBML/iframe: iframe

Does anyone know what went wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Fixed. If anyone is curious. The Canvas URL can be a page with extension (like .aspx) as long as it ends with "/". I'm not sure why when I type folder my server doesn't resolve to Default.aspx within it so I specified ".../Default.aspx/" and it doesn't load page not available any more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try with google chrome, and set debug code option (developer tools), probably some host forwarded an errorneous response to another other server, (not client).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need a css in body because this only support 520px of width max , I'm working too in iframe facebook, I dont know if change between files type index.php or index.html